# Call IQueryable method from IList using dynamic lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda, linq-expressions

I am trying to write some code that will dynamically generate lambda expression from a string. I have an `IList` for example of `Person` e.g.

```
public class Persons : IList<Person>
{
    List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
    .
    .
    .
    public IEnumerable<Person> GetPersonWithMarksAbove(int mark)
    {
        return this.persons.Where( i => i.Results.Where(x => x.Mark >= mark).ToList().Count > 0);
    }
}

Public class Person
{
    List<Result> results = new List<Result>();

    public List<Result> Results
    {
        get {return results;}
        set {results= value;}
    }
}

Public class Result
{
    public int Mark;
}
```

So what I need to do is be able to create a dynamic lambda expression that will call any `IEnumerable` methods since I can add a lot of logic in these methods to filter my `IList` elements.

This is what I've got:

```
MethodInfo containsmethod =
    typeof(Persons).GetMethod("GetPersonWithMarksAbove", new Type[] { typeof(String) });
ParameterExpression p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Persons), "p");
MethodCallExpression me = Expression.Call(p, containsmethod, Expression.Constant(8));

Expression<Func<Person, bool>> predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, bool>>(me, p);
Func<Person, bool> comp = predicate.Compile();
//persons is an object of type Persons that has been populated from the database for example 
IList<Person> datasource = persons.Where(compiled).ToList();
```

I get the following error on the line where I create the predicate variable:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Core.dll
>
> Additional information: ParameterExpression of type
>   'Namespace.Persons' cannot be used for delegate parameter of type
>   'Namespace.Person'

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your parameter expression expects a `Persons` object but the Funcs take a `Person` as a parameter.

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for the very quick reply. if i try and change that i get the following error: Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Namespace.Person]' cannot be used for return

Comment: Im not sure exactly what the problem is, just offering a tip about your code that might lead to the error. It could perhaps have something to do with the nested where call.

Comment: I think Ben is on the right track, did you change the predicate lines as follows?: `Expression<Func<IEnumerable<Person>, bool>> predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<<IEnumerable<Person>, bool>>(me, p);
Func<<IEnumerable<Person>, bool> comp = predicate.Compile();` or using var `var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<<IEnumerable<Person>, bool>>(me, p);
var comp = predicate.Compile();`

Comment: And also `GetPersonWithMarksAbove` is returning IEnumerable, not bool, so the code looks rather off.  Are you wanting to write predicates, to be used with `Where`, or are you wanting to write methods that do the filtering themselves and give you the results via IEnumerable?

Comment: I have tried that and i am now getting the following error: Additional information: ParameterExpression of type 'Namespace.Persons' cannot be used for delegate parameter of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Namespace.Person]'

Comment: thanks for pointing the above, with regards to the `GetPersonsWithMarkAbove`. I dont need to create an expression at all. This is a method that just returns an IEnumerable list of Person and i should just call the method using reflection. Please ignore the question. Its not correct. Thanks to you both.